# How to run a MATLAB executable application without having to install MATLAB Runtime on every PC

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I understand that in order for a MATLAB executable to run on Windows, it needs to have MATLAB Runtime  installed. But is there a way to copy the MATLAB Runtime folder and files on a disk or DVD with the executable file and run the application without having to install MATLAB Runtime.

I have tried using MATLAB Coder but it doesn't support most of the functions that I am using so it crashes.

I previously tried this on a flash drive. I installed MATLAB Runtime on one PC copied the whole folder to my flash which had the executable, tried to run it, but the executable came up with an error saying that it could not find the MATLAB Runtime files.

Is there any way for me to have MATLAB Runtime on a disk (or on a flash drive) without having to install it on every PC I use.

Comment: I'm Using MATLAB R2016a and MATLAB Runtime 9.0.1

Comment: Probably missing the path to the runtime folder in the `PATH` environmental variable. Make a script that adds it to `PATH`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. How would I go about making a script that adds it it `PATH`

Comment: Make a script that adds the folder to the path (remember to use relative path) and than runs the exe. I think that in linux such script is automatically created when using `mcc`. Don't about windows.

Comment: Thanks let me try it.